# how do i solve this error message for a hosted website

Tags: php, laravel

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1040] Too many connections (SQL: select * from `translations` where `lang` = en and `lang_key` = Categories limit 1) (View: /home/biglib/public_html/resources/views/frontend/partials/category_menu.blade.php) (View: /home/biglib/public_html/resources/views/frontend/partials/category_menu.blade.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message display when there is too many connection to mysql database.

You can avoid this message by closing the connection each time you do a query or open connection one time then pass the connection instance to the needed function.

In laravel you can use Service Container to init connection to mysql and the use the same connection in every function.

With this best practive you can build very lightweight app with laravel